# Facebook developers applications review

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We have created an application to allow our clients to go live on facebook.

We have submitted the application for review but we haven't received any feedback from facebook yet. it has been more than a month since we submitted the app for review. is there anything we can do to accelerate the process?

Answer (score 0):

> it has been more than a month since we submitted the app for review. is there anything we can do to accelerate the process?

No, there is not - it’s first come, first serve.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/faqs#faq_981925055227977 says:

> Due to changes to the review process and the high volume of submissions expected, it may take several weeks for submitted apps to complete review.